# AP Clients not pingable from outside

Tags: networking, routing, windows, wifi

Here's a rough scheme of my network: - https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrlJJ.png 
The network is divided into VLANs. The linksys device is connected to a VLAN20 access port. 
Clients 4, 3, 2 ping the rest of the network just fine, but
Client 1 and DC can ping the linksys ap, but can't ping clients 4, 3, 2.
What's wrong?

EDIT: Here's a brief on net config:
Router 1 divides the 172.16.0.0 network into VLANs 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 and 111 and has the corresponding addresses in these subnets: 172.16.10.1, 172.16.20.1, 172.16.30.1 etc. All the VLANs except the 111 one are routed between each other.
Switches 1 and 2 only have addresses in VLAN10. 
The Linksys WRP400 router is connected to a VLAN20 access port. Its static IP address is 172.16.20.100 (mask 255.255.255.0. Tried to apply the 255.255.0.0 but there's no such seeting). Its NAT and DHCP capabilities are disabled so it could act as an access point\switch.
I've noticed that I've also disabled the Dynamic Routing (RIP) feature along with the NAT setting. Turned it on now, but nothing changed. Should I add any static routes?

Comment: Looks like a routing or ACL issue - but you need to post more detail for anyone to have much hope solving it. Can you post full IP details along with netmasks, and the router / switch configuration?

Comment: Sure, check out the edit.

Comment: I assume that network diagram is much simplified, and you can't just flatten the network into a single subnet? Your subnet mask on the WRP400 router is correct, 255.255.255.0, all your subnets seem to require this mask.

What's the output of "tracert 172.16.50.253" from one of your wireless clients on VLAN20?

Comment: Sure, the real network is much more complicated, but I've included everything that matters in the diagram. The tracert output is: `1     1 ms     1 ms     2 ms  172.16.20.1
  2     1 ms     1 ms     2 ms  SERVER-X3650 [172.16.50.253]` ...looks like everything is correct from the client-side.

Comment: Looks sensible to me. What's the result the other way around? I'm assuming one hop for 172.16.50.1, then nothing?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what you said.

Comment: What happens if you traceroute 172.16.20.1 from 172.16.50.253? That would help verify that the routing between interfaces on the router is working OK. I'm struggling to picture the routing in my head even with the help of the diagram at the moment :-/

Comment: Woah! It outputs a timeout. So is the problem in the main router config? I was absolutly positive that it had been configured correctly. Should I post the config\some portion of the config here?

Comment: I'm tempted to say so. But that doesn't explain how ping replies are able to get from 50.x to 20.x, as if the routing was 100% broken then the replies would be lost and your traceroute from 20.x to 50.x wouldn't complete either...

Comment: Excuse me, that was a mistake. The actual tracert from 172.16.50.253 to 172.16.20.1 completes successfully. But not the other way around!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/5900/discussion-between-gac-and-khvn)